# Undirected network graph calculated by tidygraph shows more degree centrality than should be possible

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I have a cleaned data set with 26 nodes. I am placing these 26 nodes in an undirected network graph using tidygraph, where I use the `centrality_degree()` function to calculate the centrality degree. However, when I graph the resulting network, my highest possible centrality degree is 40, which should not be possible. When I change the graph to directed, this is corrected.

I somewhat confused, as other methods I have used in the past, where I manually calculated the centrality degree, I have never once come across this issue.

Is this regular behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)

nodes <- structure(list(id = 1:26, label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
    "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", 
    "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")), row.names = c(NA, -26L
    ), class = "data.frame")
    edges <- structure(list(from = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    25L, 25L, 25L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), 
        to = c(1L, 12L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 
        12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 
        22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 21L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 
        14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 
        16L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 
        21L, 1L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 
        22L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 
        24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 
        17L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 20L, 8L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 
        18L, 24L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 
        17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 10L, 
        6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 
        14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 11L, 
        1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 
        22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 
        9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 
        18L, 16L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 
        20L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 
        5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 
        21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 
        25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 21L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 5L, 
        10L, 6L, 22L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 21L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 
        4L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 
        16L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 15L, 2L, 20L, 
        8L, 17L, 21L, 1L, 12L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 25L, 
        9L, 22L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 
        16L, 24L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 
        17L, 21L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 2L, 8L, 
        21L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 
        6L, 25L, 9L, 22L, 2L, 20L, 7L, 6L, 25L, 22L, 8L), weight = c(3L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
        4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 19L, 23L, 6L, 2L, 
        11L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 21L, 2L, 
        9L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
        1L, 6L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 
        13L, 3L, 41L, 46L, 11L, 39L, 9L, 55L, 2L, 108L, 2L, 8L, 31L, 
        30L, 13L, 39L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
        1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 12L, 96L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 1L, 6L, 12L, 
        38L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 63L, 
        2L, 5L, 18L, 19L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
        3L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
        15L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 32L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 
        35L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
        9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 25L, 25L, 10L, 14L, 
        10L, 4L, 59L, 4L, 5L, 21L, 19L, 1L, 8L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
        8L, 11L, 12L, 111L, 5L, 50L, 45L, 15L, 32L, 10L, 49L, 109L, 
        1L, 8L, 28L, 39L, 53L, 13L, 48L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 20L, 3L, 3L, 
        27L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 58L, 1L, 7L, 32L, 13L, 21L, 110L, 1L, 17L, 
        27L, 124L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
        1L, 3L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 44L, 16L, 14L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 19L, 41L, 
        47L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 24L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 27L, 
        3L, 15L, 7L, 54L, 1L, 4L, 17L, 5L, 6L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 10L, 56L, 3L, 25L, 25L, 7L, 16L, 5L, 29L, 59L, 3L, 3L, 
        20L, 17L, 5L, 31L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
        13L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 16L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
        17L, 10L, 1L, 13L, 63L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -383L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

routes_tidy <- tbl_graph(nodes=nodes, edges=edges, directed=FALSE) %>% mutate(neighbors = centrality_degree())

# Filtering out 3 nodes out of the graph as they have no connections and zoom the figure way out
ggraph(routes_tidy, layout="graphopt") +
  geom_node_point(aes(size=neighbors, filter=(label!="z" & label!="s" & label!="w"))) + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(width=weight, alpha=weight)) +
  scale_edge_width(range=c(0.2, 2)) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label=label, fontface="bold", size=neighbors, filter=(label!="z" & label!="s" & label!="w")), repel=TRUE) +
  labs(edge_width="N") +
  theme_graph()
```

Comment: Is it because the degree function includes counts of loops? This is the default of `tidygraph::centrality_degree` and its underlying `igraph::degree`

Comment: With `loops=FALSE`, the same issue arises for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the whole `tidygraph` thing, stumbled over this question, got confused, and figured it'd be a nice way to get to know stuff. So, I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, but the behaviour is triggered because you have doubled edges:

```r
# Given your edges
edges %>%
  filter((from == 1 & to == 2) | from == 2 & to == 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   from    to weight
  <int> <int>  <int>
1     1     2     11
2     2     1      3
```

And those count as 2 connections in the calculation of the degree centrality. One way to remove those double edges is to convert the network to a simple network:

```r
routes_simple <-
  routes_tidy %>%
  morph(to_simple) %>%
  crystallise() %>%
  pull(graph) %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(neighbors = centrality_degree())
```

Now the maximum degree is 22 (and the heighest possible, presumably, 25).